# Do I need a specific pot to cook Japanese-style rice?

Tags: pot, sticky-rice

So, I've been rather curious lately as to what I'll be needing in order to prepare/cook some Japanese-style rice. I wanted to say sushi rice, but I believe it's prepared a bit differently—or rather, it contains a different set of ingredients (depending).

Anyway, I have a regular medium-sized pot that comes with a very flimsy metallic lid. There's almost no weight to it. Out of curiosity, I tried out a method/tutorial I found online. This person used a similar pot, but the lid was glass. I initially boiled the rice, later covering it up to let it steam, and had to stop after about 2-3 min due to the bubbles forming from the pot. I prepared everything to a T and didn't really get to eat it as I couldn't even cook it.

So, from my understanding, there's like a minimum wait time when boiling, and then you pretty much just leave the lid on for a certain amount of time for it to cook.

While I could just as easily purchase a rice-cooker, I'd like to master this method first.

Am I doing something wrong or is there typically a specific pot you'd need to use in order to do this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
[Link to resource](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8egkkpkpmM). It's not the exact one I viewed before, but the setup is the same and the process as well as the tools used is very similar. Coincidentally, I also used Nishiki short-grained rice when I did mine.

Comment: Can you more accurately explain the method you are attempting? Perhaps include a link to it?

Comment: @Catija Yes, I'll provide a link in my OP. I'll make a quick edit.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I might not have lowered the heat when my rice started boiling. So, when I put on the lid, the bubbles where just a given...even still, would anyone recommend I  use a specific pot for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, rice can be cooked in any pot. I cook quite a lot of Japanese style dishes, and as far as I can tell the rice is cooked in the same way as any other.

For myself, I've done it in good "induction-able" steel pots, as well as huge (navy galley) aluminium pots, and a couple of low-quality stainless steel things too. They're all fine.

Normally, as soon as the pot is at/near boiling, turn the heat down to a low setting and leave it in the pot until it's ready. Then take it off the heat, but leave it covered (don't peek) for another five minutes.
Generally, once you've added the water, you put the lid on. You only start the timer when it's boiled and you turn it down, though. That's probably why a glass lid is better, so you can see the boiling. It's not critical to the process, though.

Comment: +1, "not being able to cook with lid due to bubbles" is a sure sign that the stove is too hot, it has nothing to do with lid material.

Comment: If you have a lid that's not heavy, and not tight-fitting, you'll know when it's up to a good boil (without having to see through it) when it starts ratting around some.  (although, I usually that one for cooking pasta ... it might not be a fast enough notification for rice).

Comment: THANK you... I have always have been shaky with my rice-result... "keep the lid on" was so basic, I simply forgot it could be an issue....

Comment: Japanese rice does have a different cooking method involving soaking and draining the rice first.

Answer (score 1):

Rice can be made in any pot, like Carmi said. The only thing I would add is that once the rice comes to a boil bring it down to simmer and leave the lid ajar so that it doesn't spill over. And then once the rice has absorbed most of the water you can close the lid and let it sit there on low heat.